# R - Date conversion from factor

Tags: r, date

It's my first post here but I've already benefitted a lot from you all. However, I was not able to solve this issue on my own:

I am using read.csv to import a rather large set of observations, including their dates. The respective date column ('data$date') in my data frame is an integer vector and looks like the following:

```
head(data$date)
[1] "26 Oct 15" "03 Nov 15" "10 Nov 15" "17 Nov 15" "19 Nov 15" "19 Nov 15"
class(data$date)
[1] "factor"
```

When trying to convert it into a 'Date' object, I used the 'as.Date()' function:

```
tmp <- as.Date(data$date, format="%d %h %Y")
head(tmp)
[1] "0015-10-26" "0015-11-03" "0015-11-10" "0015-11-17" "0015-11-19" "0015-11-19"
```

As you can see, it does get the date kid of right, but there are two issues: 
1) Why is the year presented as "0015" instead of "2015"?
2) I assume the function returns the date in the default format. However, I want to use dates in a different format (i.e. the initial format) and I referred to the function

```
format()
```

However, this function returns a character object which I cannot use for my analyses. Thus, is there any other way to change the date format without changing the class of the object?

Thanks for your support!
Jakob

Comment: Use `%y` instead of `%Y` and the year should be resolved.

Comment: `tmp + 2000`  ? :) just kidding... I think it's because you specified `%Y` rather than `%y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to try the following

```
vec <- c("26 Oct 15", "03 Nov 15", "10 Nov 15", "17 Nov 15", "19 Nov 15", "19 Nov 15")

tmp <- as.Date(vec, format="%d %h %y")
```

It seems to fix it

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. However, can I change the format without converting the d

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. However, can I change the format without converting the date into a character object?

Comment: Seems so `fac_vec <- as.factor(vec) tmp <- as.Date(fac_vec, format="%d %h %y")` it doesnt look like it makes a difference